# Incrementing variables from R queries

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, probability

Hi so I am new in R and kind of don't know what I'm looking for. I want to measure probability of each frequency of a dust concentration so I need to divide each frequency to whole total of dust concentration frequency. By then I can continue by looking for CDF and PMF of the dust concentration.

So I have a dust probability data that has two column(Dust Concentration and its Frequencies) and it looks like this:

[image]

In my first thought, I have to increment i on this line of R queries

```
dustProb[i, "Frekuensi"]
```

that should've take specific frequency in row i so I can sum all frequency queried from it after getting that with for loops like this.

```
# the dataset is called dustData here
# dustFrequencies = dustData[i, "Frekuensi"]
for(i in dustFrequencies){
    print(dustFrequencies)
```

}

The print() part supposed to be where I sum all the variables earned through that incremented queries.

My question is:

1. Can I increment the 'i' inside that R queries
2. Was my way is too complicated or there's other way to measure probability in R?

Sorry for lots of confusion, inneficiency, and holes, I hope I was clear enough here.

Comment: I'm not sure to undertand: you want to get the probability for each dust concentration to happen, and calculate those probabilities based on the frequencies?

Comment: Yea I mean dividing each frequencies to whole frequency is the way isn't it. Then I should look for a way where I took one frequency of the table and dividing it with sum of all frequencies. But doing it one by one isn't efficient so I kinda want to increment it with for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using loops in R isn't very tidy-freindly. You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
dustData <- dustData %>%
  mutate(probabilities = Frekuensi/sum(Frekuensi))
```

The new column is the frenquency divided by the sum of all frequencies, for each dust concentration.

Comment: Does that "probabilities" includes all frequency in that row or should I make another variables for next frequency? What if I want to make whole new set of probabilites of each frequency so I can plot them?

Comment: What it does is: for each row, it takes the value of Frekuensi, divides it by the sum of all Frekuensi, then return the result in column probabilities.
For example, the first row is 11 divided by the sum of all Frekuensi and the result is written on the same row. Then, it divides 20 by the sum of all Frekuensi, and so on for all the rows. I hope that's why you expected

Comment: Looks like it works but I cannot print the "probabilities" variables. How to print it and what is the purpose of 'dustData -> dustData' ? Sorry for too much asking

Comment: No problem :) To print the column, you can do `dustData$probabilities`. The `dustData <- dustData` is typical writting of **dplyr** grammar. Instead of creating a new object, you modify the one you are working on. You can learn more about **dplyr** here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Oh so now my table has new row called "Probabilities." To call one element inside this row I can use that dustData[1, Probabilities]. Right? Thank you for helping me

Comment: Your table has a new **column** called probabilities. But yes, that's right

Comment: Ah yeah my head says column but typed row anyway, thank you for correcting. But out of curiousity, can I really creates an increment loop out of R queries? Kinda hard to find reference about that, or does all of that already packed in a simple commands like your answer?